# "in control" and "in the control"?

Tags: meaning

Good day.
Would you answer my easy question and confirm the meanings of the following two sentences?

1. The terrorists are in control of the government.
2. The terrorists are in **the** control of the government.

In 1, the party that controls is terrorists.
In 2, the party that controls is government.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*To be **in** control* means to have control over something else. So, in your first example, the subject (the terrorists) are the ones controlling the object (the government).

Your example 2 is not idiomatic. '*In control*' doesn't have an article. If you intend it to mean the reverse of example 1, the idiomatic expression is "***under** the control*":

> The terrorists are *under* the control of the government.

This means that the subject is being controlled by the object. The government, in this example, have control.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you very much and well understood.